# MySQL - Search CSV in CSV Column

Tags: mysql, sql, search, csv

I have a table with a column that has CSV.

```
TableA:

field_id  |  matches
---------------------
   1         1,2,4,6,8,11,14,56
```

Now I need to get the `field_id` that matches a user given csv. So for instance, user string is `1,4,11`, then it should return some value may be just `true`.

1.) `Find_in_set` does not work. Because it takes only one element and searches that in a SET/CSV column.
2.) Cannot use `like concat('%,', user_input , ',%')`. Because user input may not be in order.

Any other ideas? I guess this is a very common scenario.

Note: I dont need to search all records. I need to search a specific record. So in the above table, I just need to search one record that has `field_id = 1`. i.e. (`where field_id = 1`). (May not matter, but just an info)

Comment: This is not a common scenario because it is extremely bad practice to store data in an unnormalised form like a comma separated list. I suggest that you look at normalising your data, if you can the query becomes trivial.

Comment: I agree. But thats the design I can't change. Its huge product thats been in production for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume there is no straight solution with MySQL query like `Find_In_Set`. So I guess I will have to handle this with multiple queries or with Looping.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a good argument for having data in a proper relational form.  But, you can try:

```
select t.*
from t
where (find_in_set($user_input, 1) = 0 or
       find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index($user_input, ',', find_in_set($user_input, 1)), ',', -1), matches) > 0) and
      (find_in_set($user_input, 2) = 0 or
       find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index($user_input, ',', find_in_set($user_input, 2)), ',', -1), matches) > 0) and
     . . .
```

Do this for however many values you might have in the userinput set.

Comment: @KevinRave . . . I conveniently left out the more painful `substring_index` part.